# search for element of $ S_{4} $ that $ \langle g \rangle H = H\langle g \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$ S_{4} $ is the symmetric group of degree $ 4 $. $ H = \lbrace 1, (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4), (1 \ 3)(2 \ 4), (1 \ 4 \ 3 \ 2) \rbrace $ and $ N = \langle (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4), (1 \ 3) \rangle $ are subgroups of $ S_{4} $. I want found $ g,h \in S_{4} $ such that $g \notin H $ and $ h \notin N $ that $ \langle g \rangle H = H \langle g \rangle $ and $ \langle h \rangle N = N \langle h \rangle $. What this elements of $ S_{4} $?

Comment: Take $g \in N \setminus H$, $h$ of order $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|H|=4$, $|N|=8$, with $H \lhd N$. So any element $g \in N \setminus H$ satisfies $H\langle g \rangle = \langle g \rangle H$.

If $h$ is any element of $S_4$ of order $3$, then $|\langle h \rangle| =3$, so $N\langle h \rangle$ and $\langle h \rangle N$ must have order $24$ and hence they are the whole of $S_4$, so they are equal.